# Memory Mapped File gets deleted from memory

Tags: c#, memory, mutex

For some reason, when i read from a memory mapped file a couple of times it just gets randomly deleted from memory, i don't know what's going on. Is the kernel or GC deleting it from memory? If they are, how do i prevent them from doing so?

I am serializing an object to Json and writing it to memory.

I get an exception when trying to read again after a couple of times, i get `FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.`

```
private const String Protocol = @"Global\";
```

## Code to write to memory mapped file:

```
public  static  Boolean                 WriteToMemoryFile<T>(List<T> data)
        {
            try
            {
                if (data == null)
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("Data cannot be null", "data");
                }

                var mapName = typeof(T).FullName.ToLower();
                var mutexName = Protocol + typeof(T).FullName.ToLower();
                var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
                var capacity = serializedData.Length + 1;

                var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen(mapName, capacity);
                var isMutexCreated = false;
                var mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out isMutexCreated);
                if (!isMutexCreated)
                {
                    var isMutexOpen = false;
                    do
                    {
                        isMutexOpen = mutex.WaitOne();
                    }
                    while (!isMutexOpen);
                    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(mmf.CreateViewStream());
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(serializedData);
                    streamWriter.Close();
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
                else
                {
                    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(mmf.CreateViewStream());
                    streamWriter.WriteLine(serializedData);
                    streamWriter.Close();
                    mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

## Code to read from memory mapped file:

```
public  static  List<T>                     ReadFromMemoryFile<T>()
        {
            try
            {
                var mapName = typeof(T).FullName.ToLower();
                var mutexName = Protocol + typeof(T).FullName.ToLower();

                var mmf = MemoryMappedFile.OpenExisting(mapName);
                var mutex = Mutex.OpenExisting(mutexName);
                var isMutexOpen = false;
                do
                {
                    isMutexOpen = mutex.WaitOne();
                }
                while (!isMutexOpen);

                var streamReader = new StreamReader(mmf.CreateViewStream());
                var serializedData = streamReader.ReadLine();
                streamReader.Close();
                mutex.ReleaseMutex();
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(serializedData);
                mmf.Dispose();
                return data;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return default(List<T>);
            }

        }
```

Comment: Could you add the line where the exception occures? What sequence of calls `WriteToMemoryFile` and `ReadFromMemoryFile` do you have? Do you realize, that `mmf.Dispose()` releases the `Memory Mapped File` ?

Comment: i call Dispose only after calling OpenExisting method, which doesn't delete the memory file.

Comment: That's true. I can only assume, that `mmf` finalizer is calling by `GC` ,  try to hold reference on `mmf` outside `WriteToMemoryFile`

Answer (score 4):

The process that created the memory mapped file must keep a reference to it for as long as you want it to live. Using `CreateOrOpen` is a bit tricky for exactly this reason - you don't know whether disposing the memory mapped file is going to destroy it or not.

You can easily see this at work by adding an explicit `mmf.Dispose()` to your `WriteToMemoryFile` method - it will close the file completely. The `Dispose` method is called from the finalizer of the `mmf` instance some time after all the references to it drop out of scope.

Or, to make it even more obvious that GC is the culprit, you can try invoking GC explicitly:

```
WriteToMemoryFile("Hi");
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();  
ReadFromMemoryFile().Dump(); // Nope, the value is lost now
```

Note that I changed your methods slightly to work with simple strings; you really want to produce the *simplest* possible code that reproduces the behaviour you observe. Even just having to get `JsonConverter` is an  unnecessary complication, and might cause people to not even try running your code :)

And as a side note, you want to check for `AbandonedMutexException` when you're doing `Mutex.WaitOne` - it's not a failure, it means you took over the mutex. Most applications handle this wrong, leading to issues with deadlocks as well as mutex ownership and lifetime :) In other words, treat `AbandonedMutexException` as *success*. Oh, and it's good idea to put stuff like `Mutex.ReleaseMutex` in a `finally` clause, to make sure it actually happens, even if you get an exception. Thread or process dead doesn't matter (that will just cause one of the other contendants to get `AbandonedMutexException`), but if you just get an exception that you "handle" with your `return false;`, the mutex will not be released until you close all your applications and start again fresh :)

Comment: hmmm, i tried to use GC.KeepAlive() method because of that. But it didn't help. I tried GC.KeepAlive(mmf) and GC.KeepAlive(mmf.SafeMemoryMappedFileHandle), but it didn't make any difference. I don't know what else to try

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic That's not how `GC.KeepAlive()` works - try reading the documentation. `KeepAlive` just makes sure the instance isn't collected *before the call to* `GC.KeepAlive()`. You need to have some context within which the memory mapped file is valid, and that context needs to have the same lifetime as the memory mapped file, and have a reference to it. It's hard to recommend any concrete practices without knowing more about your application.

Comment: i'll read the docs, thanks for a suggestion. Concerning the context, i have a server running in a service which needs to have configuration files for alot of stuff, and those conf files are needed for every call to the server. So to avoid constant calling to the database, or using a filesystem to read/write for every call, i was thinking to use a memory file. There is also a second app that runs on a same machine that needs access to those memory files as well.

Comment: @Nikola.Lukovic Well, if both of those applications are in .NET, perhaps it would be better to just have them communicate using something like .NET remoting or WCF? Memory mapped files are kind of low level and hard to synchronize efficiently (mutexes aren't exactly cheap, and you might end up heavily serializing all the work you're doing). Combined with some decent caching and reasonable cache-invalidation mechanisms might make this work quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, the problem is that the MMF loose its context as explained by Luaan. But still nobody explains how to perform it:

1. The code 'Write to MMF file' must run on a separate async thread.
2. The code 'Read from MMF' will notify once read completed that the MMF had been read. The notification can be a flag in a file for example.

Therefore the async thread running the 'Write to MMF file' will run as long as the MMF file is read from the second part. We have therefore created the context within which the memory mapped file is valid.